# Strange behaviour of GHCI after importing Gnuplot

Tags: haskell, gnuplot, ghc, ghci

I recently tried one simple example on plotting using Haskell wrapper for Gnuplot using this [example](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/hydramax-533365/quick-and-dirty-plotting-with-haskell-gnuplot-35230/) on ubuntu. It works fine, but after I close the graph window and type anything in GHCI terminal, it doesn't show it being typed. On entering text and pressing return it executes it in a normal way.

I tried with unloading all modules but to no avail. Has someone else faced it earlier ?

GHC : 7.6.3
Linux : Ubuntu 12

So, is it a bug?

Comment: In a standard Ubuntu/Gnome terminal window, that would be?

Comment: yes its after I command it as ghci and it loads to Prelude.

Comment: Calling `plotFunc` starts the interactive gnuplot terminal (the equivalent of running 'gnuplot') and passes the arguments necessary to create your plot. This seems to be a bug related to the way that `process` runs the gnuplot terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is an old bug (2 years), http://trac.haskell.org/gnuplot/ticket/1 (and it's one of the reasons I stopped using Gnuplot with Haskell – the other being the apparent inability to programatically close Gnuplot windows).

As noted in the issue tracker, you can make ghci show what you write again by typing :reload (or, equivalently, :r), but then you lose all your bindings and stuff so it's not a good workaround.

Edit: By the way, I'm on OS X, probably 10.7/10.8 something when I encountered this bug.

Comment: thanks for confirming and link..would you suggest what else you use for plotting then ?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find any other solution at the time, mostly because I didn't have the time too look around too much. I hear about [Chart](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart-1.1) and [Diagrams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams) now and then, though, so you might find something you like there. Apparently someone is working on something of a port of [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org), a plotting package for R that is good, but for that we will have to wait. ([Blog post with some examples using Chart](http://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2013-12-24-24-days-of-hackage-charts.html).)

Comment: Just noticed this plotting package on Hackage that sounds interesting and relevant. I haven't tried it, though. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plot